# Travis-CI: Can the version of Node installed on all VM images match the latest (stable) on the node.js images?

Tags: node.js, gulp, travis-ci

I'm running my CI through Travis and using Gulp to compile my assets for a project where the main language is not Node. I'm therefore using the version of Node they give you on all VM images for this (see http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Environment-common-to-all-VM-images).

One of the Gulp plugins I need requires at least v0.12.0 of Node. I know I can install it as a pre-build step but I don't want to have to do this every time the build runs.

As far as I can see, it's not possible to change the version on all images but it's currently v0.10.36 which is a bit behind the latest stable version you can access on node.js images.

Does anyone know if there's another way to get a newer version?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used Travis a lot but isn't this simply a matter of removing the version from your `.travis.yml` file?

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer so thought it's worth posting it.

All images come with NVM so you can set the Node version in the `before_install` step:

```
before_install
  nvm install 4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a specific node version listed on the doc you site: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Environment-common-to-all-VM-images.

I do see:

> Runtimes:
>   ...
>   Language-specific workers have multiple runtimes for
>   their respective language (for example, Ruby workers have about 10
>   Ruby versions/implementations).

and

> Node.js VM images #
>   Node.js versions #
>   Node runtimes are built using nvm.

So my .travis.yml starts with

> language: node_js
>      node_js:
>        - '0.12'

And in my build log I see

> $ nvm install 0.12                                                       4.68s
>
> ################################################################## 100.0%
>
> Now using node v0.12.7

4.68 seconds for NVM to switch nodes doesn't seem like much of a penalty.
Perhaps this is not as big an issue as you originally thought?

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. My problem is that Python is the primary language for my project not Node (Node is used for building static assets) so the worker I'm on is the Python-specific one which doesn't offer NVM or any other control over the version of Node used.